# Detecting invalid or corrupt jpg files with jpeg package in R

Tags: r, try-catch, jpeg, corrupt

I'd like to use the `jpeg` package (or similar) to detect corrupted .jpg files. I am sharing this code with users who have had trouble installing `exiftool` so I'd prefer to use packages that do not require that program.

I want my code to catch images that are completely corrupt or that are partially corrupt (i.e., you can see part of the image, but some of it is cut off).

When an image is corrupt, the `readJPEG` function returns:

```
Error in readJPEG(photos[35]) : 
  JPEG decompression error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x7b 0x28
```

When an image is partially corrupt, the function returns:

```
JPEG decompression: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
```

I want to write a function that will return FALSE if the image is "good" and TRUE if it is corrupted or partially corrupted. So far, I can't get my function to work if the image is partially corrupted (it returns FALSE). What am I doing wrong?

[Here's an example of a "partially corrupt" image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i9LcOK9eY4oWwkZpCAfQ36mAxe-bL30c) - the bottom half got cut off when it was transferred to a new device.

```
library(jpeg)

    # Function to "catch" bad photos
is_corrupted <- function(x){
  tryCatch({
    check <- readJPEG(x)
    return(FALSE)
    },
    error = function(e)
      return(TRUE),
    warning = function(w)
      return(TRUE),
    message = function(m)
      return(TRUE)
    )
}
```

#### **EDIT:** Try number 2...

I created a modified function based on Ben's suggestions, but it still isn't returning `TRUE` if an image is completely corrupt. I also don't like how it tests the photo twice. Any recommendations appreciated!

To test the function, you can use three jpgs... (1) any valid jpg from your computer, (2) the "partially corrupt" file linked in this question, and (3) reference a file that doesn't exist to throw an error that will be caught by `tryCatch` (e.g., `is_corrupted("")`.

```
is_corrupted <- function(x){
message <- capture.output(check2 <- readJPEG(x), type = "message")
if(length(message) > 0) {
  corrupt <- TRUE
} else {
corrupt <- tryCatch({
    check <- readJPEG(x)
    return(FALSE)
  },
  error = function(e) # catch "corrupt" images
    return(TRUE)
  ) 
}
return(corrupt)
}
```

Comment: The returned line for partially corrupt files looks like a `message` and not a `warning`.  You could try replacing 'warning' with 'message' inside `is_corrupted`.

Comment: Thanks @BenNutzer! I did try that - no dice, but thanks for the suggestion :( I'll edit the function so folks know that didn't work either.

Comment: I tested your approach using `purrr::quietly(readJPEG)` and the wrapped function did not return either messages or warnings. My uninformed guess is that it has something to do with the underlying `.Call` to another function. A workaround could be to use `capture.out(readJPEG(x), type = "message")` and evaluate on the output. My bottom line is: Your code is fine, it just does not work. Maybe someone else could confirm/refute this.

Comment: I tried again, but I can't get it to work and I think I'm missing something really simple. Will you take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this one is tricky. I think you need to have the error checking before the capturing part. I will post a temporary (ugly) solution, and hopefully someone else posts a more elegant and straightforward one.

```
readJPEG2 <- purrr::safely(readJPEG)
```

Let `purrr` do the error checking and if there is none, proceed with examining the output:

```
fun <- function(x){
          if(is.null(readJPEG2(x)$error)){
                    message2 <- capture.output(readJPEG(x), type = "message")
                    if(length(message2) > 0){
                              return("partially corrupted")
                    } else {
                              return("complete")
                    }
          } else {
                    return("corrupted")
          }

}
```

I do not know how robust this solution is but maybe it helps you even so.

Comment: Ugly or no, it definitely works (thank you!!!!). :P Do you know how to stop it from writing the message "JPEG decompression: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment" (like a "quietly = TRUE" option)?

Comment: Glad you find it helpful! I also tried to suppress the message but failed (`suppressMessages`). I think it is the same issue that prevents your code from working properly.

Comment: I added an issue to Simon's gitHub page (author of `jpeg`). I'll update here if there are any changes.